# 'Element Not Visible Exception' when trying to click on a Search option using webdriver selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I get an 'Element Not Visible Exception' when trying to click on a Search option on a webpage. The element is not hidden, and I have put a time.sleep(10) so the page has enough time to load. Please suggest why I am getting this error and how I can get around it.

I want to click on 'New Search' option in the code.

```
<a class="newsearch btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static">
    <div id="TBnewsearch"><img src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" 
    alt="New search" />
    </div>
        <span>New search</span>
</a>
```

Please find my code for clicking on it below :

```
time.sleep(10)

New_Search = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(' #Toolbar > table > tbody > tr > td.TBGroup.TBGroup1 > a.newsearch.btn.btn3d.tbbtn')
action2 = ActionChains(browser)
action2.move_to_element(New_Search).click()
action2.perform()
```

I've also tried doing a simple find and click on the element but get the same exception at the New_Search.click() step.

time.sleep(15)

```
New_Search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Toolbar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]')
New_Search.click()
```

I've tried using WebDriverWait as suggested by Debanjan below, but the expected condition isn't satisfied and I get a timeout exception.

```
time.sleep(15)

WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Toolbar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]')));
New_Search.click()
```

Comment: Can you test these locators in the Dev tools and check if they are pointing to the right element on the page? In the console use `$x()` to test XPaths and `$$()` to test CSS selectors. If it returns 0, you know there's something wrong with your locator. If it returns 1, you are good to go. If it returns more than 1, you will need to verify that the element you are looking for is the first element returned. If it's not, you will need to craft a new locator. I have a feeling that your current locators is returning 2 nodes, out of which the first one is invisible.

Comment: @GPT14, tried your suggestion, and turns out I have 4 elements having the same selector, the same xpath, the same id and same everything else on my page. Th element I want to click is second. Now I need to figure how to differentiate them from each other.
Thanks a lot for your suggestion :)

Comment: Try to access the target element using that elements ancestors. Keep going one level up till you find a node that is uniquely identifiable and then use relative xpath (`//`) to traverse down to your element. You can also use ordinals/index to locate the element, but i would not recommend it as they will make your test brittle. If possible update the question with a bigger snippet of the HTML or the applications URL

Comment: @GPT14, thanks a lot for your suggestion :)
worked and now I am able to click my element successfully !

Comment: @GPT14 if you'll post you comment as an answer I'll accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you test these locators in the Dev tools and check if they are pointing to the right element on the page? In the console use `$x()` to test XPaths and `$$()` to test CSS selectors. If it returns **0**, you know there's something wrong with your locator. If it returns **1**, you are good to go. If it returns **more than 1**, you will need to verify that the element you are looking for is the first element returned. If it's not, you will need to craft a new locator. I have a feeling that your current locators is returning 2 nodes, out of which the first one is invisible.

Try to access the target element using that elements ancestors. Keep going one level up till you find a node that is uniquely identifiable and then use relative xpath (`//`) to traverse down to your element. You can also use ordinals/index to locate the element, but i would not recommend it as they will make your test brittle. If possible update the question with a bigger snippet of the HTML or the applications URL